# Why does Dialogflow intent gives "Default Response Not available" with webhooks?

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm working on a bot, and some of the menu options are giving a "Not available" as the "Default Response". The options that are failing all use webhooks, so I assume the problem is there.

Even without the system we're using, just in Dialogflow web, when testing the bot, the correct intents are triggered, and the correct actions and contexts; the only thing is the default responses seem to be empty.

However, in the "Diagnostics Info", I can see the correct information I should have had, as the fulfillment text.

Does anyone know what could the problem be?

Comment: Please add more explanation, code, and screenshot. Your question is not very clear I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it was a very simple thing. There was no error, the response from my webhook method was correct, it's just that on the Dialogflow test console, I had to select "Google Actions" instead of "Default Response", and I didn't know that when I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have face and solved this today.

Dialogflow show  "Not available" as the "Default Response" because it get Error in my JS cloud function when processing the response.

After fixing the part that will get Error, I can get the reply normally